# How can I prove that $n < 2(n + 1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality

How can I logically prove that $n < 2(n + 1)$ assuming $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

This is probably a silly question but I am very tired.

Comment: This is part of a larger homework problem where I have to show that for all numbers greater than A the function F(x>A) will be greater than C. This is how far I've gotten.

Comment: You can't. If $n < -2$ then the inequality is the other way. Is there a constraint like $n >0$?

Comment: @SeanLake: Yes I realized that as soon as I posted it and I've added the domain now. Like I said I am absolutely exhausted and I need to finish this go to to sleep

Comment: @stas $2(n+1) - n = n+2 > 0$, therefore $2(n+1)>n$.

Comment: @ErickWong Yes... I forgot you can subtract the n to get zero... I need coffee

Comment: Have you tried a proof by induction?

Answer (score 3):

Since $n$ is a natural number,
$$0 \le n$$
And we also have
$$0 < 1 + 1$$
So adding the two inequalities
$$0 < n + (1+1)$$
Adding $n$ to both sides,
$$n < n + (n + (1 + 1))$$
By associativity and commutativity,
$$n < (n+1)+(n+1)$$
By reversing the distributive rule,
$$n < (1+1)(n+1)$$
And simplifying,
$$n < 2(n+1).$$